# Three.js - Model cannot receive any shadow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm currently new and learning about three.js. And i'm using `react-three-fiber` to make it happen with React, but i stumbled upon a problem. The model however, cannot receive any shadow from another model. I've tried to use `obj.castShadow = true` and `obj.receiveShadow = true` to one of the receiving shadow model object on the parent and the children as well but it shows no difference. Is there any way to cast a shadow to another model?

And the shadow.. it seems very rough. Is there any way to smoothen it?

[image: 1]

Here's my sandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-newton-np1sw

Code:

```js
import React, { Suspense, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "react-three-fiber";
import { OBJLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader";
import { OrbitControls} from "drei";
import { Mesh } from "three";

import billboard from "../assets/models/billboard.obj";
import bridge from "../assets/models/bridge.obj";

const Model = ({ modelPath }) => {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState();
  useMemo(() => new OBJLoader().load(modelPath, setObj), [modelPath]);
  if (obj) {
    obj.castShadow = true;
    obj.traverse((children) => {
      if (children instanceof Mesh) {
        children.castShadow = true;
      }
    });
  }
  return obj ? <primitive object={obj} /> : null;
};

const ShadowedModel = ({ modelPath }) => {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState();
  useMemo(() => new OBJLoader().load(modelPath, setObj), [modelPath]);
  if (obj) {
    obj.castShadow = true;
    obj.receiveShadow = true;
    obj.traverse((children) => {
      if (children instanceof Mesh) {
        children.castShadow = true;
        children.receiveShadow = true;
      }
    });
  }
  return obj ? <primitive object={obj} /> : null;
};

const Lights = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.1} />
      <spotLight
        castShadow
        position={[-50, 50, 20]}
        intensity={0.5}
        shadow-mapSize-shadowMapWidth={2048}
        shadow-mapSize-shadowMapHeight={2048}
        shadow-camera-left={-50}
        shadow-camera-right={50}
        shadow-camera-top={-50}
        shadow-camera-bottom={50}
      />
      <pointLight position={[10, -10, -20]} intensity={0.3} />
      <pointLight position={[0, 10, 5]} intensity={0.3} />
      <spotLight intensity={1} position={[0, 1000, 0]} />
    </>
  );
};

const Billboard = () => {
  return (
    <mesh
      castShadow
      position={[-15, 5, -35]}
      scale={[0.05, 0.05, 0.05]}
      rotation={[0, 20, 0]}
    >
      <Model modelPath={billboard} />
    </mesh>
  );
};

const Bridge = () => {
  return (
    <mesh
      castShadow
      receiveShadow
      position={[10, -40, -80]}
      // position={[-80, -40, -150]}
      scale={[0.15, 0.15, 0.15]}
      rotation={[0, 10.2, 0]}
    >
      <ShadowedModel modelPath={bridge} />
    </mesh>
  );
};

const Shadow = () => {
  return (
    <group>
      <mesh
        receiveShadow
        rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}
        position={[-20, -32, -40]}
      >
        <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[500, 500]} />
        <meshLambertMaterial attach="material" color={"lightblue"} />
      </mesh>
    </group>
  );
};

const MegatronModel = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Canvas
        shadowMap
        colorManagement
        camera={{ position: [0, 0, 5], fov: 60 }}
      >
        <OrbitControls
          enablePan={Boolean("Pan", true)}
          enableZoom={Boolean("Zoom", true)}
          enableRotate={Boolean("Rotate", true)}
        />
        <Shadow />
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Bridge />
        </Suspense>
        <Billboard />
        <Lights />
      </Canvas>
    </>
  );
};

export default MegatronModel;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is indeed receiving shadows. The problem is that you have several `PointLight`s at full intensity that are washing everything out into white. Even shaded areas are blown out to white. See here, I've disabled all your `PointLight`s and only kept the spotlight and ambient light so you can see the shadows again:

[image]

I recommend you use as few lights as possible to make rendering less resource-intensive. Adding so many lights could lower your framerate, overheat laptops, and drain more battery on cell-phones. For a pretty realistic lighting setup, I like using a single hemisphere light with a directional light [like in this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=hemisphere#webgl_lights_hemisphere). Hemisphere makes it feel like there's atmospheric light coming from the top, with reflected ground light from the bottom.

As far as pixelated shadows go, you're using a large 2048x2048 map, but it's spread out across too large an area. I see you're trying to set `left, right, top, bottom` distances but those only apply to [DirectionalLight](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/shadows/DirectionalLightShadow), which uses an orthographic camera. Left, right, top, & bottom properties don't apply to SpotLight, which uses a perspective camera. If you want to make the Spotlight shadowmap narrower, [use the `.angle` property](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/SpotLight.angle).

Comment: Thank you very much! I've spent hours to figuring out what's going on but it turns out it just a dumb mistake that i made. Guess I need to revisit & learn much more from the documentation. Again, thanks!